# filter dictionary of type [String: [object]] for specific key in object arrays

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm showing users a tableview that looks like the contacts view in the sense that the data source is a dictionary of type [String: [User]] and so I'm showing section headers with the first letter of the Users name.

Now, I want to allow them to search by the users first name... but I can't get this to work.

These are the dictionaries... the friends will hold data like this `["A" :[Users whose first name start with an A]]` and so on

```
var friends = [String: [User]]()
var filteredFriends = [String: [User]]()
```

This is my filtering code with `searchText` being the first name I want to search by

```
self.filteredFriends = self.friends.filter{friend in
return friend.firstName.lowercased().contains(searchText)}
```

What I want to do is make `filteredFriends` have all of the values of `friends` whose users first names start with the text.

How do I make this work with a dictionary like mine?

Thanks

More Info:

```
 Class User {
     var firstName: String?

     init(name: String){
        self.firstName = name
     }
 }
```

Sample scenario:

```
friends = ["A" : [User(name: "Anthony), User(name: "Arnold")], "B" : [User(name: "Barry")]]
filteredFriends = friends

searchText = "an"
```

Desired filteredFriends (end result) = `["A" : [User(name: "Anthony)]]`

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output. Also supply a declaration of User. In other words, give all information needed for us to construct the desired code.

Comment: @matt question updated

Comment: Very good, thanks.

Comment: @matt no, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple way. You just have to cycle through the whole dictionary, like this:

```
// these are your initial conditions

class User {
    let firstName: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.firstName = name
    }
}
let friends : [String:[User]] = 
    ["A" : [User(name: "Anthony"), User(name: "Arnold")], 
     "B" : [User(name: "Barry")]]
let searchText = "an"

// and here we go...

var filteredFriends = [String:[User]]()
for entry in friends {
    let filt = entry.value.filter{$0.firstName.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchText)}
    if filt.count > 0 {
        filteredFriends[entry.key] = filt
    }
}
```

Now `filteredFriends` contains the desired result.

Comment: you can use `enumerated()` on a dict, to get the keys/values directly

Comment: @Alexander But you don't have to. I like the tuple notation better. Basically our solutions are identical, except that yours is much more verbose (not that that's a bad thing: verbose can be clearer).

Comment: Yep, they are. I usually write pretty verbose var names on SO in lieu of comments where appropriate. I expect OP will change them if they wish.

Comment: Though I did put in a (micro?) optimization, in that if the search term matches the first initial, the array is taken without any filtering.

Comment: This works perfectly. @matt how can i utilize mapping to remove a user from one of these dictionaries of [String : [User]] if I have their firstName? Thank you

Comment: @Walker If you have a different question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would use `map` to transform the input dictionary to the output dictionary, by filtering each of its values (`User` arrays). Unfortunately, `Dicationary.map` returns `[(Key, Value)]` (an array of `(Key, Value) tuples), not a new Dictionary. I'll take the more conventional, iterative approach instead.

Note: For those who are about to circle jerk around using functional styles everywhere, who are about to suggest using `reduce`: no. Pull out a profiler, and look at how slow and power-consuming it is to generate dictionaries with reduce. Especially important on a mobile device with limited battery.

Here's how I would do it:

```
let allFriends = [String: [User]]()
var filteredFriends = [String: [User]]()

let searchText = "a".lowercased()

for (initial, allFriendsWithInitial) in allFriends {
    if initial.lowercased() == searchText {
        // don't even have to bother filtering `friends`
        filteredFriends[initial] = allFriendsWithInitial
    }

    let filteredFriendsWithInitial = allFriendsWithInitial.filter{
        $0.firstName.lowercased().contains(searchText)
    }

    if !filteredFriendsWithInitial.isEmpty {
        filteredFriends[initial] = filteredFriendsWithInitial
    }
}

print(filteredFriends)
```

Comment: @Hamish Thanks. You're a trusted community member in my eyes, you're more than welcome to edit my answers in future cases.